# Knockout script not hitting applyBindings

Tags: knockout.js

I have a fairly simple screen that is utilizing Knockout script. I have a really odd issue.

I have QA/Staging/Production environments set up, and my screen loads and runs perfectly locally and in my QA environment. However, when I migrate my scripts and page to my Staging server, Knockout doesn't hit the ko.applyBinding(vm) code. It does do it on my QA server. I am using Chrome debugger tool to break it at that point to verify.

Here is my code, less some functions...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
vm = new function () {

        var thisVm = this;

        this.lastName = ko.observable(),
        this.firstName = ko.observable(),
        this.dob = ko.observable(),
        this.cityList = ko.observable([])

        //Load the CityList
        this.loadCityList = function (callback) {
            var data = {};
            new ajaxJsonHelper().invoke("ServiceDelivery.aspx/GetCityList", data, vm.loadCityListCallback, showAjaxFailure, false);
        }

        this.loadCityListCallback = function (result) {
            if (result.d != null) {
               vm.cityList(result.d);
            }
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
 });
```

Comment: Have you ruled out any infrastructure-related issues, like your Production environment possibly having a proxy server that is caching old files?  Or did you try it after a complete browser cache clean/refresh on your machine?

Comment: I've cleared all cache on the server and client machine. I can see that the files are correct there, and all functions are hit, it just never hits the applyBindings. It's the weirdest thing I've ever seen.

Comment: I apologize, when I said "...migrate to my Production server" I meant Staging. I have edited my original post to reflect that.

Comment: You say the rest of the code in the document.ready block is being run? and I would say it might be better to have the normal object instantiation pattern.
var ViewModel = function () {...};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

Comment: Yes, the rest of the code in the document.ready block is being run. I can try the normal instantiation, it's just odd that it works this way in my other applications, as well as this one, in a different environment. Everything runs, but it's a blank screen because nothing is being bound to the elements.

Comment: Not sure, but when you do `ko.applyBindings()` it attempts to find the body element [(ko source)](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/04a8f84e4ae19a3bf61fcafb3d563ad457461eda/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L439).  Could try forcing it onto an element with an id somewhere, `ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('ko-main'));`

Comment: First, I'd like to apologize and thank you for your time, Tim and Matthew. Apparently, a migration script on the db side didn't go through properly which resulted in a table not being loaded on Staging, and it happened to be used for the first function in the block, which caused an error and stopped everything from loading any further. However, no error was shown in the console. An entire day wasted. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a few things at play here. And I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7m98nubg/) to demonstrate the concepts working.

> Note: I've removed the inner code for clarity sake.

```
var vm = function() {
  var thisVm = this;

  console.log("inside view model");
};

$(document).ready(function() {    
  ko.applyBindings(new vm());
});
```